# Transfer Encoding chunked with okhttp only delivers full result

Tags: retrofit, rx-java2, okhttp, chunked

I am trying to get some insights on a chunked endpoint and therefore planned to print what the server sends me chunk by chunk. I failed to do so so I wrote a test to see if OkHttp/Retrofit are working as I expect it.

The following test should deliver some chunks to the console but all I get is the full response.

I am a bit lost what I am missing to even make the MockWebServer of OkHttp3 sending me chunks.

I found this retrofit issue entry but the answer is a bit ambiguous for me: [Chunked Transfer Encoding Response](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2632)

```
class ChunkTest {
    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val rule = RxImmediateSchedulerRule() // custom rule to run Rx synchronously

    @Test
    fun `test Chunked Response`() {
        val mockWebServer = MockWebServer()
        mockWebServer.enqueue(getMockChunkedResponse())

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(mockWebServer.url("/"))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .client(OkHttpClient.Builder().build())
                .build()
        val chunkedApi = retrofit.create(ChunkedApi::class.java)

        chunkedApi.getChunked()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({
                    System.out.println(it.string())
                }, {
                    System.out.println(it.message)
                })

        mockWebServer.shutdown()
    }

    private fun getMockChunkedResponse(): MockResponse {
        val mockResponse = MockResponse()
        mockResponse.setHeader("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked")
        mockResponse.setChunkedBody("THIS IS A CHUNKED RESPONSE!", 5)
        return mockResponse
    }
}

interface ChunkedApi {
    @Streaming
    @GET("/")
    fun getChunked(): Flowable<ResponseBody>
}
```

Test console output:

```
Nov 06, 2018 4:08:15 PM okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$2 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[49293] starting to accept connections
Nov 06, 2018 4:08:15 PM okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 processOneRequest
INFO: MockWebServer[49293] received request: GET / HTTP/1.1 and responded: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
THIS IS A CHUNKED RESPONSE!
Nov 06, 2018 4:08:15 PM okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$2 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[49293] done accepting connections: Socket closed
```

I expected to be more like (body "cut" every 5 bytes):

```
Nov 06, 2018 4:08:15 PM okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$2 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[49293] starting to accept connections
Nov 06, 2018 4:08:15 PM okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 processOneRequest
INFO: MockWebServer[49293] received request: GET / HTTP/1.1 and responded: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
THIS
IS A 
CHUNKE
D RESPO
NSE!
Nov 06, 2018 4:08:15 PM okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$2 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[49293] done accepting connections: Socket closed
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The OkHttp Mockserver does chunk the data, however it looks like the LoggingInterceptor waits until the whole chunks buffer is full then it displays it.

From this [nice summary about HTTP streaming](https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/6bfade6431e9ffb7fe88#transfer-encoding):

> The use of Transfer-Encoding: chunked is what allows streaming **within a single request or response.** This means that the data is transmitted in a chunked manner, and does not impact the representation of the content.

With that in mind, we are dealing with 1 "request / response", which means we'll have to do our chunks retrieval before getting the entire response. Then pushing each chunk in our own buffer, all that on an `OkHttp network interceptor`.

Here is an example of said `NetworkInterceptor`:

```
class ChunksInterceptor: Interceptor {

    val Utf8Charset = Charset.forName ("UTF-8")

    override fun intercept (chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val originalResponse = chain.proceed (chain.request ())
        val responseBody = originalResponse.body ()
        val source = responseBody!!.source ()

        val buffer = Buffer () // We create our own Buffer

        // Returns true if there are no more bytes in this source
        while (!source.exhausted ()) {
            val readBytes = source.read (buffer, Long.MAX_VALUE) // We read the whole buffer
            val data = buffer.readString (Utf8Charset)

            println ("Read: $readBytes bytes")
            println ("Content: \n $data \n")
        }

        return originalResponse
    }
}
```

Then of course we register this Network Interceptor on the OkHttp client.